# Good book for Unix Internals

Tags: unix

am very much interested in unix. Want to learn in and out. 
Can you guys help me by listing some books which can make me a wizard?
Ultimately I want to become a unix programmer.

I am not a novice user in Unix.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want system administration knowledge, or programming knowledge?

For programming:

- [Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321525949)
- [Unix Network Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411551)
- [The Art of Unix Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131429019)

For system administration:

- [Automating Linux and System Administration](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430210591)
- [Unix and Linux Administration Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131480057)

Comment: I want a kind of both but going one by one. Learning internals is my first priority.

Comment: APUE is THE reference here. It's one of 2 books that doesn't leave my desk.

Comment: Can I ask you which is the other one?

Comment: @PaulRubel I'd be interested to know too (some years later, apologies...)

Answer (score 5):

As other responders have noted, Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment (APUE) is indispensable.

Other books that you might want to consider (these have more of a Linux focus, but are a good way to become familiar with Unix internals):

- [Linux System Programming](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596009588): well written, understandable introduction to the Linux API.  Not as much depth as the others, but a good way to get the "lay of the land."
- [The Linux Programming Interface: A Linux and UNIX System Programming Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593272200): more up to date than APUE, but focused on Linux.
- Understanding the Linux Kernel (O'Reilly): learn about Unix programming from the perspective of an OS implementer, rather than a application developer.

Answer (score 4):

check these out: [UNIX Internals: The New Frontiers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131019082)  , [The Design of the UNIX Operating System](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132017997) ,[UNIX Systems Programming: Communication, Concurrency and Threads](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130424110)