# writing data into fifo file in python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, gpio

I have recorded one audio file and I am converting that file into base64 format.Now I want to write this audio file into a fifo file.
Code is written below:

```
import os 
import base64
import select
os.system("mkfifo audio1.fifo")
with open("audio1.fifo") as fifo:
     select.select([fifo],[],[fifo])
     with open("out1.wav","rb") as audioFile:
         str = base64.b64encode(audioFile.read())
         fifo.write(str)
```

But above code only creating fifo file but not writing anything in it.Plz give any suggestions.

Comment: Did you open it for reading on the other side?

Comment: What are you using as the reader? And how do how do start/run that please?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi   I have opened fifo file to which data need to be written.What do u mean by other side sir??

Comment: A FIFO is meant to exchange data, not to store it. It usually cannot be written to if there is nothing on the other end to receive the data. To quote from [the linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html): "The FIFO must be opened on both ends (reading and writing) before data can be passed."

Comment: @MisterMiyagi   Can u plz tell me if i want to read the audio data from uart of raspberry pi 3b and play the same data at the same time at 3.5mm audio jack (By considering that i am transmitting some audio data from transmitter side Raspberry pi).How to do it??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Receiving data through uart in raspberry pi 3b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59676120/receiving-data-through-uart-in-raspberry-pi-3b)

Comment: @0andriy No sir i didn't get answer

Comment: You created duplicated questions

Comment: @0andriy No sir not exact duplicate questions. Here i want to write a recorded file into fifo file but in another question I wanted to write fifo file while receiving from UART OF RPI

Answer (score 0):

Use `+` model can at the same time support read and write

```py
import base64
import select
os.system("mkfifo audio1.fifo")
with open("audio1.fifo", "wb") as fifo:
     select.select([fifo],[],[fifo])
     with open("out1.wav","rb") as audioFile:
         str = base64.b64encode(audioFile.read())
         fifo.write(str)
```

The same time read and write two different files:

```py
# maker sure the be read file's has some data.
with open("a.file", "w") as fp:
    fp.write("some data")

# now a.file has some data, we create a b.file for write the a.file's data.
with open("b.file", "w") as write_fp, open("a.file", "r") as read_fp:
    write_fp.write(read_fp.read())

# for bytes data
with open("b.file", "wb") as write_fp, open("a.file", "rb") as read_fp:
    write_fp.write(read_fp.read())
```

Comment: Still not writing into fifo file

Comment: @kunal If your error msg is `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`, you need to make your data be a bytes data or use `r+` model.

Comment: sir, it is not showing any error .The program is running continuously but not writing anything into fifio file

Comment: the var `str ` has any data?

Comment: yes sir it must have data because I tried one program in which I recorded audio file converted it into base64 format and then transmitted it using ser.write(str) function .This was working really well.

Comment: I can't make sure but I will add a example that show the same time write and read two different files.

Comment: The wav file is only ever read from, why would it need to be opened in read and write mode?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Sorry, I change it.